# Density of states equal to 1?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, density-of-states

I have found a problem with my quantum mechanics background theory, more specifically regarding the identity operator and the momentum density of states.
The following equation
$$<p|\hat{x}|\psi> = k \int dp' <p|p'><p'|\hat{x}|\psi> = k<p|\hat{x}|\psi>,   $$
where k is the density of states in momentum space and $<p|p'> = \partial_{pp'}$, seems to imply that k=1 always. What am I missing?

Comment: I am struggling to understand your notation completely. What are your states $| p \rangle$? Are they normalized? Orthogonal? Both? What is the symbol $\partial_{pp'}$? Is it a Kronecker delta? A Dirac delta? A partial derivative??

Comment: momentum states, both normalized and orthogonal, and I believe dirac delta.

Comment: If they are complete and orthogonal then they resolve to the identity without any $k$...

Comment: I see, that would make sese. Although Sakurai never seems to make a clear distinction. Given a specific problem, is there any way I could infer wehter my momentum states are complete and orthogonal? Or am I always able to use either representations for the identity in terms of momentum states?